# Correlation of complex random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation

If I have two complex standard normal variables vectors (10,1) $M_i$ and $N_i$ as below,
$M_i = a_i+jb_i$ and $N_i = c_i +d_i, (1<i<10)$

How can I get correlation coefficients of these vectors?